# Creating textField with unique name for each in a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

im beginner level programmer on Java. I would like to create textField in a for loop but i also want it to have a unique name (for calling after loop). For ex. I have this loop;

```
for (int i =0;i<x;i++)

        {


            Composite composite_10 = new Composite(composite_20, SWT.BORDER);
            composite_10.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(230, 230, 250));
            composite_10.setBounds(x1, y1, 542, 76);

            txtBaseSeri = new Text(composite_10, SWT.BORDER);
            txtBaseSeri.setMessage("Base Seri");
            txtBaseSeri.setToolTipText("");
            txtBaseSeri.setBounds(x2, y2, 95, 21);
            txtBaseSeri.setText("41");
            txtBaseSeri.setTextLimit(7);
}
```

Here, I want the second Textfield have a name like txtBaseSeri1, then txtBaseSeri2... so that i can call them after exiting the loop. Is there any way to do that ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use an array of textfields. Otherwise you will have a lot of variables.

Comment: you are right. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the second Textfield have a name like txtBaseSeri1, then txtBaseSeri2 - Is there any way to do that?

No. Use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead and add your text fields to that list, for example like this:

```
List<Text> txtBaseSeri = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    // ...

    Text txt = new Text(composite_10, SWT.BORDER);
    // ...

    txtBaseSeri.add(txt);
}
```

Afterwards, you can access each `Text` object through its index, like

```
Text first = txtBaseSeri.get(0);
Text second = txtBaseSeri.get(1);
// ...
```

or you can loop through them, like

```
for (Text txt : txtBaseSeri) {
    // in each loop iteration, txt will be set to the next element
    // ...
}
```